# Using CSS how do I make an image retain its width-to-height ratio and cover its parent?

Tags: css

I don't want to use a background image and `background-size: cover` because I want to use the `picture` element so it will choose the right image for the screen.

I want to make sure it's at least 100% of both the width and the height, but retain its ratio.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you're probably looking for object-fit: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: min-height and min-width to 100% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `min-height` and `min-width` , set theme both `100%` and add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element. like this:

```
.parent-element-of-picture{
     overflow:hidden;
}
.picture{
     min-height:100%;
     min-width:100%;
}
```

you can also set `width=100%` and `min-height:100%` , or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not relying on Internet Explorer, you could make use of the `object-fit` property. You can use this as follows:

```
.picture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover; //or contain
}
```

To support IE, there are JS polyfills:

- https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit
- https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fit-polyfill

Comment: object-fit isn't supported in IE or Edge

Comment: uh yes that is also what I mentioned, which is why i put the polyfill links there?